# Is this sum on power free number and Euler constant true?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

Let $p_{n,r}$ be $r$-th smallest $n$-power free number. For example $p_{2,7}$ is the $7$-th square free number and $p_{5,7}$ is the $7$-th smallest $5$-th power free number.

Let $q_{n,r}$ be the $r$-th number which contains (or is divisible by) a $n$-th power. For example $q_{2,7}$ is the $7$-th smallest number which contains a square and $q_{5,7}$ is the $7$-th smallest number which contains a fifth power.

We define $\alpha_n$ for $n \ge 2$ as the ratio of the sum of the $n$-th power free number to the sum of the $n$-th power containing numbers i.e.

$$
\alpha_n = \lim_{r \to \infty}\frac{p_{n,1}+p_{n,2}+\ldots + p_{n,r}}{q_{n,1}+q_{n,2}+\ldots + q_{n,r}}.
$$

**Question**: Is it true that

$$
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_n}{n} = 1 - \gamma
$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant?

**Motivation**: I ran a program and the sum seem to converge to 0.422785 which is close to $1-\gamma$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your definition of $\alpha_n$ is $\infty/\infty.$  Do you mean $\alpha_n = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{p_{n,1}+p_{n,2}+\ldots+p_{n,k}}{q_{n,1}+q_{n,2}+\ldots+q_{n,k}},$ or $\alpha_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\text{sum of the }n^{\text{th}}\text{ power-free numbers less than }k}{\text{sum of the }n^{\text{th}}\text{ power-containing numbers less than }k},$ or something else?

Comment: Yes it is on the form $\infty/\infty$. Your first interpretation is the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**. The equality is true. [Since](http://rgmia.org/papers/v7n4/densityintegers.pdf) $$Q_{n}\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\zeta\left(n\right)}+O_{n}\left(x^{1/n}\right)
 $$ we have, using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), that $$ \sum_{p_{n}\leq N}p_{n}=Q_{n}\left(N\right)N-\int_{1}^{N}Q_{n}\left(t\right)dt
 $$ $$=\frac{N^{2}}{2\zeta\left(n\right)}+O_{n}\left(N^{1+1/n}\right).
 $$ In the same spirit we get $$ \sum_{q_{n}\leq N}q_{n}=\left(1-Q_{n}\left(N\right)\right)N-\int_{1}^{N}\left(1-Q_{n}\left(t\right)\right)dt
 $$ $$=\frac{N^{2}}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\zeta\left(n\right)}\right)+O_{n}\left(N^{1+1/n}\right)
 $$ so we have $$\alpha_{n}=\frac{p_{1,n}+p_{2,n}+\dots}{q_{1,n}+q_{2,n}+\dots}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{p_{n}\leq N}p_{n}}{\sum_{q_{n}\leq N}q_{n}}=\zeta\left(n\right)-1
 $$ hence $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\alpha_{n}}{n}=\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\zeta\left(n\right)-1}{n}=\color{red}{1-\gamma}$$ as wanted (for a proof of the last idenity see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433797/why-does-the-sum-n1-zetan-1-1/1433807#1433807)).

Comment: This is a good starting point

Comment: with $P$ the primes and $p_{.,n}$ the $n$th power free numbers : $\displaystyle\sum_m p_{m,n} m^{-s} = \prod_P (1+\sum_{k < n} P^{-sk})= \prod_P \frac{1-P^{-sn}}{1-P^{-s}} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(sn)}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_m q_{m,n} m^{-s} = \zeta(s) (1-\frac{1}{\zeta(sn)})$

Comment: @Marco Cantarini - Elegant work. Here is a generalization that I am thinking will work. The equality looks to be true even if we define $\alpha_n = \frac{f(p_{n,1}) + f(p_{n,2}) + \ldots}{f(q_{n,1}) + f(q_{n,2}) + \ldots}$ where $f$ is any function Riemann integrable in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @user60930 Yes, it follows from my proof; the limit is essentially $$\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta(n)}f(N)}{(1-\frac{1}{\zeta\left(n\right)})f(N)}.$$