# $\sum_{k= 2}^\infty (\zeta(k) - 1)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Show that $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (\zeta(k) - 1)$$ converges and find the limit.

(Hint : Deduce that $\zeta(s) = 1 + O(2^{-\sigma})$ where $s = \sigma + it$, $\sigma \geq 2$.)

$\textbf{Proof}$ Let $s = \sigma + it$ with $\sigma \geq 2.$ Then $$\zeta(s) = 1 + \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^s} = 1 + \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^\sigma e^{it \log n}}.$$

Since $s$ is complex and complex number cannot be compared, is it a bit vague to prove $$\zeta(s) = 1 + O(2^{-\sigma}).$$ 
Even if I ignore the imaginary part, it is not clear why $$\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^\sigma}\leq \frac{C}{2^\sigma}$$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: Related: [Why does $\sum_{n>1}(\zeta(n)-1) = 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433797/why-does-the-sum-n1-zetan-1-1)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. However, is the hint given in  this exercise make sense ? I am interested in deducing it.

Comment: The hint makes sense to show convergence. If you can show that $\zeta(n) - 1 = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$ then convergence follows by the comparison test as $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges. Also note that for the purpose of this exercise there is no need at bringing imaginary numbers into the picture. Simply take $s = n  = $ "an integer" (i.e. $t=0$) to begin with.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I can deduce the hint now.