# Sum of Zetas Inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, riemann-zeta

I am here because I am unsure about how to prove the following:
$$s-1 \geqslant \sum_{n=2}^{s-1}\zeta(n)\, \left\lbrace s\mid s\in\mathbb{Z^{+}},\, s\geqslant 2 \right\rbrace$$
where $\zeta(n)$ denotes the Riemann Zeta function. I believe it to be true, given the conditions, but I have not come up with a method sophisticated enough to prove such an inequality. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433797/why-does-the-sum-n1-zetan-1-1/1433807#1433807

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thank you for your hint, but I'm still a little bit lost because I don't know how to use that information to prove the inequality. I'm trying to prove for finite $s$, and I don't quite see the connection. Thank you, once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty(\zeta(k)-1)
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^k}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{n^k}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2\left(1-\frac1n\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\right)\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for finite $s$,
$$
\begin{align}
1
&\gt\sum_{n=2}^{s-1}(\zeta(k)-1)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{s-1}\zeta(k)-(s-2)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
s-1\gt\sum_{n=2}^{s-1}\zeta(k)
$$

Comment: Oh my word, thank you so much, Robjohn! I wasn't sure if we were allowed to perform the last three steps. Would you mind if I asked why we were able to do that? Thanks to both of you, again!

Comment: The finite sum is less than $1$ because the first term missing from the infinite series is $\zeta(s)-1\ge\frac1{2^s}$. This means that $$\sum_{k=2}^{s-1}(\zeta(k)-1)=1-\sum_{k=s}^\infty(\zeta(k)-1)\le1-\frac1{2^s}\lt1$$ The second step follows since $$\sum_{k=2}^{s-1}1=s-2$$ The last inequality is simply the previous with $s-2$ added to both sides.

Comment: Understood. Thanks, Robjohn, for helping me again. Have a great day.