# Proof that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\bigl(\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1 / n^k\bigr)$ doesn't converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How to prove that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\Bigl(\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^k}\Bigr)$  doesn't converge [as wolfram said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlI4G.png) ?

Comment: There's a serious typo that appears twice here - the actual question is the one answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k} \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^k}\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$$

As the harmonic series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$, is divergent, it follows that the double summation is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}$$

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so the whole thing diverges.

Comment: Just wondering, what if you exclude the $k=1$ term then?

Comment: @GarethMa all of the sums contain $\frac{1}{1^k} = 1$ so the limit of the terms is nonzero, the sum can't converge. If you exclude $n=1$ and $k=1$, then the sum is $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}= 1$. To see this, interchange the summations, and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{n}} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 -n} = 1$. The last equality is easy to show, expanding the summand by partial fractions and observing that the resulting series telescopes.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Also might be interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433797/why-does-the-sum-n1-zetan-1-1

Comment: @failedentertainment nice comment...

Comment: The argument "this diverges so the whole thing diverges" works here because all terms are nonnegative.