# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}} = \frac{1}{1-e^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

**Question**

How do you derive the following result:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}} = \frac{1}{1-e^2}$$

**More context**

It is a well known fact that:
$$\zeta(2n) = a_n\pi^{2n}$$
Where I'll call $a_n$ *the coefficient of the zeta function at even integers*. By using the explicit formula for the zeta function at even integers, we get that:
$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n-1}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
So by using this definition, we see that the original series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$$

Now, some of you may wonder; what about the non-alternating case? i.e. what is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n-1}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

It turns out that this is nearly identical to the taylor series for $\cot(x)$:

$$\cot(x) = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(2x)^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Plugging in 1, we get:

\begin{align}\cot(1)&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!} \\\\ &=  1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\end{align}

Then, subtracting $-1$, multiplying by $-1$ and then dividing by 2, we get:

$$\frac{1-\cot(1)}{2} =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n-1}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

...which is the desired series for the *non-alternating* case. So back to the question; how do you derive the series in alternating case?

Comment: Use the lemma here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3713153/7933

Comment: Have you heard of $\coth$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes, now when I look up the taylor series for $\coth(x)$ it seems very close to my question...

Comment: Especially since $\coth 1=\frac{e^2+1}{e^2-1},$ right? ;-)

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes, I feel a little embarrassed now XD. Thanks for your help.

Comment: all this follows from $\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi z}-1} = -i\pi+\sum_n \frac1{z-n}= -i\pi+\frac1z+\sum_{n\ne 0} \sum_{k\ge 0} z^{k}n^{-k-1}$